# SpringBoot: How to reload application.property file in few second without restart application?

Tags: properties, configuration, spring-boot, reload

I am working on a java web service application which is using SpringBoot framework. I put properties into the application.properties file parallel to the jar. Afterward, I restart the application and new properties are picked by web service.

Now my requirement is, my web service keep reload the property file after few time (lets say 5000ms) and I do not want to restart the web service. Is there any way in SpringBoot to achieve this?

Thanks,
Harsh

Comment: Harsh, did u resolve it?

Comment: if yes can u pls let me know how to achieve this with sample code

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring cloud starter dependencies, you will get a /refresh endpoint for this purpose to POST to. It refreshes the configuration from property files without interrupting the service.